# Поиск подстроки с определенным набором символов в нужном порядке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Приветствую и сразу хочу подчеркнуть, что не интересует какое-либо другое решение, кроме как одна единственная операция с помощью функции `preg_match()`! И в данном случае, не важно почему.

Итак, поиск производится в пути URL, например: `/some/path/123-c456-c7-9/`. Забегая вперёд скажу, что в вышеуказанном примере нам нужна подстрока **123-c456-c7-9**.
Необходимо найти ту часть пути, которая может состоять из групп, разделённых  дефисом, а каждая группа может состоять только из цифр и символа "`c`" в нижнем регистре. Количество таких групп может быть от 1 до `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Условия поиска:

- символ "`c`" может быть только в начале группы и в единственном числе
- в каждой группе должна быть минимум одна цифра
- подстрока не может заканчиваться или начинаться с символа дефиса
- искомая подстрока может быть только последней частью пути
- слэш (`/`) в конце исходной строки - не обязателен

Составил следующее регулярное выражение `(?<=/)(c?\d+-?)+(?=/$|$)`.

```
<?php
$source = [
    '/path/1/',
    '/path/c1/',
    '/path/123-456/',
    '/path/c123-456/',
    '/path/123-c456/',
    '/path/c123-c456/',
    '/path/c/',
    '/path/12с3-456/',
    '/c123-456/path/',
    '/path/-123/',
    '/path/123-/',
    '/path/c123-/',
];
foreach($source as $path) {
    if(preg_match('#(?<=/)(c?\d+-?)+(?=/$|$)#', $path, $matches)) {
        echo $matches[0], ' - OK', PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $path, ' - FAIL', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
1                - OK
c1               - OK
123-456          - OK
c123-456         - OK
123-c456         - OK
c123-c456        - OK
/path/c/         - FAIL
/path/12с3-456/  - FAIL
/c123-456/path/  - FAIL
/path/-123/      - FAIL
123-             - OK // Ошибка, дефис в конце
c123-            - OK // Ошибка, дефис в конце
```

Практически во всех случаях отрабатывает нормально, но не могу победить случай, когда подстрока заканчивается на дефис, т.е. такого плана `/123-456-/`.
Собственно, с этой проблемкой связано моё обращение к сообществу и буду благодарен за подсказки в её решении.

Comment: [`(?<=\/)(c?\d+)+(-c?\d+)*(?=\/$|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/nuARk0/1)?

Comment: [`~/\K(?:c?\d+(?:-(?:c?\d+))*)+(?=/?$)~`](https://regex101.com/r/FxLBsI/2)

Comment: @Yaant, ваша регулярка ощутимо лучше, но пропустит такой вариант: `'/path/1c1-111/'`.

Comment: мне кажется регулярные выражения и длина в int max отправят вас в очень длительное ожидание. причем даже не длина у вас а число групп. то есть длина в разы больше

Comment: А, ну тогда `(?<=\/)(c?\d+){1}(-c?\d+)*(?=\/$|$)`

Comment: @Yaant, похоже, что это оно! По крайней мере, я понял вашу логику и, если проявится какой-то баг, то уже подправлю сам. Оформляйте ответ.

Comment: Не, регулярки - не мой конек (а PHP - и подавно), а в ответе все ж неплохо бы и какие-то пояснения дать. Давайте уж Вы сами и ответите. :)

Comment: @Yaant, так ведь дело в том, что регулярки - это и моё "слабое звено" )) Я их не люблю и это похоже, что взаимно ))

Comment: Оптимизированный по скорости вариант: [`~/\K(?:c?\d+)(?:-c?\d+)*(?=/?$)~`](https://regex101.com/r/nuARk0/2) @Deonis если есть необходимость в ответе с пояснениями, я мог бы их написать )

Comment: @Эдуард Пишите-пишите, больше некому, похоже, на Вас вся надежда. :)

Comment: @Эдуард, для того, чтобы написать ответ, ни у кого разрешения спрашивать не нужно ;) Мне пояснения не нужны, т.к. код я читать умею, но пояснения пригодятся новичкам, которые могут просматривать эту тему в будущем.

Comment: Лучше уж `~/\Kc?\d+(?:-c?\d+)*(?=/?$)~` или `~/(c?\d+(?:-c?\d+)*)/?$~` (все нужные значения в первой подмаске, `$matches[1]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
preg_match('~/\Kc?\d+(?:-c?\d+)*(?=/?$)~', $path, $matches)
```

См. [пример работы кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/#preview) и [регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/nuARk0/3).

**Подробности**

- `/` - символ косой черты
- `\K` - оператор очистки буфера текущего совпадения (тут он удаляет символ косой черты)
- `c?` - один или ноль повторов (т.е. опционально) символа `c`
- `\d+` - одна или более цифр
- `(?:-c?\d+)*` - 0 или более повторов следующей последовательности:

  - `c?` - один или ноль повторов символа `c`
  - `\d+` - одна или более цифр
- `(?=/?$)` - позитивный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, требующий присутствия сразу после текущей позиции необязательного символа `/` и конца строки.